# c++ static local variable initialization in dll cause _CrtIsValidHeapPointer exception

Tags: c++, exception, dll, static

I have an exception is a dll i'm using when initializing a static local variable to a class instance.
The exception occurs when returning from the class constructor.

The exception I get in release is:

> ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000BA3529A2.

and in debug I get a debug assertion:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: E:\Sandbox\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
>   File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
>   Line: 1516
>
> Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

This is the function that fail (Part of the CImg library which is excellent!):

```
static const CImg<Tuchar>& jet_LUT256() {
  static CImg<Tuchar> colormap; // <--- static local variable decleration
// exception here. after returnning from the CImg constructor :-( 
  cimg::mutex(8);
  if (!colormap) {
    colormap.assign(1,4,1,3,0);
    colormap[2] = colormap[3] = colormap[5] = colormap[6] = colormap[8] = colormap[9] = 255;
    colormap.resize(1,256,1,3,3);
  }
  cimg::mutex(8,0);
  return colormap;
}
```

When the project was running as an exe everything worked fine.
Problem started when I made it a dll, and used it in another exe.

Comment: Class instances can't have "static local" variables. Do you mean static *member* variable, or that the constructor has a static local variable? Perhaps you could show the code for the constructor?

Comment: There is no question here.  Are you asking what those messages mean?

Comment: I'm asking how to get rid of them...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Found out that the problem was that I used the /NOENTRY property (big NONO!)

(because when I converted it from exe to dll I had a link error with unresolved function `mainCRTStartup`)

removed the /NOENTRY from Properties->Linker->Advanced and error is gone.